# I want to convert from Array<String?> to Array<String>?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this `String` array:

```
var parsedWeatherData: Array<String>?
```

And I want to add some weather data from JSON file using this code:

```
val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST)
parsedWeatherData = arrayOfNulls<String>(weatherArray.length())
```

The error is that the `parsedWeatherData` requires `Array<String>?` and not `Array<String?>`. How can I change the value from `arrayOfNulls()` to be of type `Array<String>?`?

Comment: `filterNotNull` maybe will work for you?

Answer (score 1):

`Array<String>?` basically means this will be either a null value or an Array Of String.

`Array<String?>` means the array will contain null or String values.

You will be better changing the type of `parsedWeatherData` to `Array<String?>` if you are sure you will not assign it a null value later on. If you want it to remain as `Array<String>?` then you can use

```
parsedWeatherData = weatherArray.map { it }.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `arrayOfNulls()` returns an array of objects of String type with the given size, initialized with null values.
So `parsedWeatherData` is obviously an `Array<String?>` because values are null.

If you need `Array<String>` or `Array<String>?` you need to make sure that all the strings contained in the array are NOT null.

If think you should do something like this:

```
val weatherList = mutableListOf<String>()
for (i in 0 until weatherArray.length()) {    
    weatherList.add(weatherArray.getString(i))
}
parsedWeatherData = weatherList.toTypedArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an Array with non-nullables, you need to use the constructor with a lambda that initializes each element in the array, like this:

```
val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST)
parsedWeatherData = Array(weatherArray.length()) { index ->
    weatherArray[index]
}
```

And a couple suggestions... Lists are a little easier to work with, and you can make it non-nullable and just allow it to be empty when it doesn't have data. Then you don't have to handle null cases. So I'd do it like this:

```
// The property:
var parsedWeatherData: List<String> = emptyList()

// Parsing data:
val weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST)
parsedWeatherData = List(weatherArray.length()) { index ->
    weatherArray[index]
}
```